# ASP.NET HttpWebRequest POST returns "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed." Only on VS dev Server

Tags: asp.net, http

I'm using HttpWebRequest to POST data to an ASP.NET webpage (currently running on the ASP.NET Development Server) Here's the code;

```
string url = "http://localhost:3333/MySite/";
WebResponse response = null;
try {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData = "data=test";
    byte[] dataBtyes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    request.UserAgent = "Custom Agent";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = dataBtyes.Length;

    Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(dataBtyes, 0, dataBtyes.Length);
    stream.Close();

    response = request.GetResponse();
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Using a HTTPModule I'm intercepting the requests from "Custom Agent" and sending back a custom Header. This works fine for GET requests, however the data I want to send could potentially exceed the limits allowed for GET requests, so I'd like to use POST (as above).

I have tested this code on a real IIS server and it works, however the Visual Studio development server causes an exception "405 Method Not Allowed" every time GetResponse() is called after POST data is sent (GET works fine.)

Can anyone offer an explanation as to why the development server seems to be rejecting POST requests?

Edits: Question title and body updated to emphasise the problem residing with the VS dev server.

Comment: Please find a way to capture the Request and add it to your question. Also it'd be good to see the Response (if any). You can get it with the Firebug plugin or if you want some light-weight sniffer try using this one http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html

Comment: I'm having trouble sniffing local packets on the loopback. (note, the question has been updated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've discovered that the "405 Method Not Allowed" error is returned when POSTing to folder addresses. (Using the question code above)

The **VS development server** seemingly doesn't allow;

> - http://localhost:1234/WebSite
> - http://localhost:1234/WebSite/

... but is happy with;

> - http://localhost:1234/WebSite/Default.aspx

The **IIS server** produces the error for;

> - http://localhost:1234/WebSite

... but is happy with;

> - http://localhost:1234/WebSite/
> - http://localhost:1234/WebSite/Default.aspx

Comment: Oh shit, that remind me of that IIS have Handler mappings specific for /. Which mean handler mappings for aspx, svc and so on don't apply automatically - if you point to i.e. /WebSite/ instead of /WebSite/Default.aspx